# cplusplus.com says that the past-the-end of an std::string "shall not be dereferenced"

Tags: c++

I would like it if you could clear up some confusion for me. I was writing a function that removes duplicate characters in a string, e.g. "AB --> "AAABB".

```
void remove_dups(std::string& str) { 
    std::string::iterator it = str.begin();
    while (it != str.end()) {
        if (*(it+1) == *it) {
            str.erase(it+1);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work when I test it. However, I was wondering, shouldn't there be a fencepost issue? When 'it' is the end of the string, the if statement looks at the non-existent next character. According to cplusplus.com,

***The past-the-end character is a theoretical character that would follow the last character in the string. It shall not be dereferenced.*** (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/end/)

So I'm wondering why my function seems to pass the tests and how I can rewrite the whole thing in an elegant way to get around the fencepost issue. (Go easy on me, guys. I'm a n00b.)

Rewriting it like

```
void remove_dups(std::string& str) { 
    std::string::iterator it = str.begin();
    while (it != str.end()) {
        if ((it+1) != str.end() && *(it+1) == *it) {
            str.erase(it+1);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

seems inelegant.

Comment: @chris I don't think that will help. It seems this algorithm is to remove duplicate consecutive characters.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, That's exactly what `std::unique` does.

Comment: @chris Good point. It would still require a call to resize the string after that, though, wouldn't it?

Comment: @hvd, It goes nicely with `erase`. Could call it the erase-unique idiom I guess, but it's really erase-remove with a different algorithm.

Comment: @chris Sure, that would work too. `str.erase(std::unique(str.begin(), str.end()), str.end());` and `str.resize(std::unique(str.begin(), str.end()) - str.begin());` should have the same effect, and I don't think either is more or less complicated than the other.

Comment: @hvd, Not really, no, but one won't work if the iterator doesn't support `operator-`. The main reason for `erase` would be to keep it looking similar to the erase-remove idiom. I haven't seen the `resize` one, but it should work the same way for the most part.

Comment: @chris Ah, okay, I was only thinking about strings, not about other containers. That's also why I didn't see that as a problem with the `it-1` in my answer (nor with the `end()-1` in Jefffrey's answer). (Edit: to clarify: I understand that subtracting an integer from an iterator is different from subtracting two iterators.)

Comment: dereferencing `std::string::end()` is UB, as far as the standard goes. In most major vendors, it yelds '\0', except for when empty-string / short-string optimization is active, which I guess your code didn't trigger.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680181/is-it-safe-to-dereference-end/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I'm wondering why my function seems to pass the tests

Undefined behaviour doesn't mean it won't do what you want. It may do exactly what you want, just for the wrong reasons. I'm guessing that the undefined behaviour manifests itself as getting you the `\0` character, which is not likely to compare equal to other characters in your string.

> and how I can rewrite the whole thing in an elegant way to get around the fencepost issue

There are a lot of options, but my personal preference would be something like

```
if (it != str.end()) {
  ++it;
  while (it != str.end()) {
    /* compare *it and *(it-1) */
  }
}
```

But beware that `erase` has to move elements. Suppose you delete 20 characters in total. You will move the remainder of the string one character back, 20 times. You don't need to do that, if you slightly modify your algorithm:

```
void remove_dups(std::string& str) { 
  std::string::iterator src = str.begin();
  std::string::iterator dst = str.begin();
  if (src != str.end()) {
    ++src;
    ++dst;
    while (src != str.end()) {
      if (*src != *(src-1)) {
        *dst = *src;
        ++dst;
      }
      ++src;
    }
    str.resize(dst - str.begin());
  }
}
```

This approach also has the benefit that it works even if `erase` moves the string around in memory, which may cause your iterator to break.

Answer (score 1):

Standard allows to compare with one past last array element, you are not allowed to dereference it. So you can compare its address, to verify if loop should end but you are not allowed to read contents. Since iterators are mostly pointers, then this rule also applies to string, vector, ...

Also, note that non sequence version of string::erase returns iterator to character that occupies removed element, you might use it as new loop iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cleanest solution is to stop at the end of the string (the last character of the string), since at that point, no further actions are performed anyway.

Therefore `while (it != str.end())` should be `while (it != str.end() && it != (str.end() - 1))`.

Comment: `str.end() - 1` won't work if the string may be empty, and I don't see anything to suggest that empty strings are invalid.