# Is it safe to dereference end()?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a function with the following signature:

```
std::string f(const char *first, const char *last) {
    std::string result;
    std::for_each(first, last, some_lambda_which_appends_to_result);
    return result;
}
```

and an overload for std::string which calls it:

```
std::string f(const std::string s) {
    return f(&*s.begin(), &*s.end());
    // The one below would assume that the string is not empty
    //     f(& s.front(), & s.front() + s.size());
}
```

However, this may be unsafe (dereferencing s.end() might be a red card offense in itself).
Is there a safe way to get a pointer to the beginning of characters and a one-past-the-end pointer (two null pointers would be fine in case of an empty string),
or do I have to write

```
std::string(const std::string& s) {
    return s.empty() ? std::string() : f(& s.front(), & s.front() + s.size());
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with string's constructor?

Comment: What do you think about accepting the other answer? Since the one currently accepted doesn't seem to be valid anymore.

Comment: Although @Angew 's answer may not be correct (anymore) w.r.t. `end()`, he gave me what I wanted (a way to safely call the other overload) in a way that's valid all the way back to C++98.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not safe to dereference `end()`. However, you can use either `c_str()` or `data()` to achieve what you need:

```
std::string(const std::string& s) {
    return f(s.data(), s.data() + s.size());
}
```

Comment: Argh, blinded by science!